# Not pre-trained binary transformer model

Tags: long-short-term-memory, transformer, pytorch, binary-classification

I stacked with a problem. My default Transformer model totally does not learn how to evaluate python logical expressions, like: **'(False and not True) xor False or (not False and False)'**. Model should understand how eval such expressions and return True or False answers. Model after training returns all the time False answer. To test how does my logical expressions generator, tokeniser and custom dataset works, I wrote LSTM model with MultiheadAttention layer. And such LSTM model after training successfully evaluates logical expressions. So all parts in my code works fine, except Transformer model.

So my question is, is it theoretically possible to train an untrained Transformer model to make it a binary classifier?

Because as I correctly understand LSTMs have a sequential nature and are effective in capturing dependencies in sequential data, such as natural language sequences. The LSTM-based model, with the use of bidirectional LSTM layers and attention mechanism, might be able to learn the patterns and dependencies present in the logical expressions more effectively, resulting in accurate evaluations.
On the other hand, transformers are designed to capture global dependencies and are highly effective in tasks involving long-range dependencies. However, they might not be as effective when dealing with sequential data or capturing fine-grained sequential patterns. But I don't see any problems why my Transformer doesn't trained to eval expressions and after that return correct answer.